# Existe alguma maneira de fazer um componente ouvir uma função React Native?

Tags: react, react-native, bind

Preciso fazer um bind para uma função que me retorna se um item está marcado ou não, no entanto a função que me retorna isso só é executada uma vez, existe uma maneira de fazer bind para essa função?

```
<List dataArray={this.state.talhoes}
        renderRow={(talhao) =>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.select(talhao)}>
        <Card>
          <CardItem>
            <Thumbnail square size={40} source={{ uri: talhao.public_url_screenshot }} />
            <Text style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }} > {talhao.name}  </Text>
            <Right>
              <CheckBox checked={this.checkSelected(talhao)} /> //Aqui o problema
            </Right>
          </CardItem>
        </Card>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    }>
  </List>
```

Comment: Já testaste `checked={this.checkSelected.bind(this, talhao)}` e depois usares `checkSelected(talhao, event){`?

Comment: @Sergio não funciona, me da a resposta que ele aguarda um Boolean

Comment: Felipe: vi agora que esse checkbox é um componente. Qual é a biblioteca? deve ter um `onChange` que podes usar como estavas a usar com o `checked`. Esse `checked` deve ser o estado do componente que o `propType` exige ser um `Boolean`..

Answer (score 0):

Você deve atribuir um valor a partir do `state` do seu componente ou uma propriedade que é atualizada externamente, porque você precisa que o metodo `render` do seu componente seja executado para que a mudança apareça na tela.

Um exemplo de como resolver isso de maneira simples:

```
// Seu metodo checkSelected, pode alterar o state em vez de retornar o valor a ser definido no <CheckBox/>
checkSelected (value) {
  // exemplo hipotético ok?
  const checked = value !== undefined
  this.setState({ checked })
}

// Quando o state é alterado, o método render é executado e o valor de checked será atribuido corretamente de acordo com o estado atual
<CheckBox checked={this.state.checked)} />
```

Comment: Acho que você cometeu um pequeno erro relacionado à lógica que do exemplo original. Quem deve modificar o _state_ do componente é o método `select(talhao)`, que é executado no handler do evento `onPress` de `TouchableOpacity`. Assim, a chamada de `checkSelected(talhao)` pode continuar onde está.

Comment: Tudo bem, só foi um exemplo simples mesmo, a ideia era fortalecer o uso do setState e da atribuição do state p/ atualizar o componente ;)